# Logout of IdentityServer 4 in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: redirect, logout, identityserver4

I am using Identity Server 4 for authentication in my ASP.NET CORE 2.0 Web Application. I am not able to Log Out the user.

I have a link on the click of which I am calling the following piece of code in Javascript

```
var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);
mgr.signoutRedirect();
```

The above code tries to redirect to the Logout action (HttpPost) of the `AccountController` in the Identity Server web application, however, I get a `HTTP 404`. The URL, that I'm hitting is like below:

> https://www.demo.com/PIdentity/account/logout?logoutId=CfDJ8Gm9-HlsFDlKoXXEkMIomhRIbKpHhsku9jDUSDrdIYKFhqj-WnfV8T3-KCsZG9D0I_d_u9X0i8x1uFxrjZfOIcjL--W5uSd4VHY2qF7n8iWTmrn_i-mHQWOJlAJ8cZFcia6egupkqNv5-YqKyq1A_Rb2GTt3yeiTMX58UHyz96-FtcOPN6h07fA78W-Z_uRZefuvb2ocnWT9UHQsqS7T-IAyurOnnjLq97CbjGoDiCy99bnBlHm-1jPPc4F5NkQD8Q8NcIVQc2vg1M5VcxX4Ms7TCem-b3nAVlW8PWJq4aLdgvnatLBAoTzWjPdO6sD_wNarpUqxAX7ZqXHDECuP49g01BenW1zdsi75QLs3qihG

The action method does not get hit from Fiddler too.

My AccountController has a Logout action like below:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
  await _signInManager.SignOutAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
  _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
  return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
}
```

Can someone please guide me.

Following is the code that I have in my JS

```
var config = {
//authority: "https://localhost:44326/",
authority: "https://www.demo.com/DemoIdentity/",
client_id: "sett.web.js",
redirect_uri: window.location.origin + "/callback.html",
post_logout_redirect_uri: window.location.origin + "/DemoWeb/Dashboard",

// these two will be done dynamically from the buttons clicked, but are
// needed if you want to use the silent_renew
response_type: "id_token token",
scope: "openid profile api1",

// this will toggle if profile endpoint is used
loadUserInfo: true,

// silent renew will get a new access_token via an iframe 
// just prior to the old access_token expiring (60 seconds prior)
silent_redirect_uri: window.location.origin + "/DemoWeb/silent.html",
automaticSilentRenew: true,

// will revoke (reference) access tokens at logout time
revokeAccessTokenOnSignout: true,

filterProtocolClaims: false
};

var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);
var access_token = ""
Oidc.Log.logger = window.console
```

And the code on the click of the logout button I have given at the top of this post.

Comment: Let's clarify some stuff here - what is the type of your client - SPA or Core Web App? Because you are saying that it is Core Web App, but the code that you have shown (`Oidc.Manager` etc.) is part of the `oidc-client-js` library, which is supposed to be used with SPA'a (or other JavaScript based) clients.

Comment: It is an ASP.NET Core Web App

Comment: Then why you are using the javascript library? Can you give some code and configuration for clarification?

Comment: I have added the JS code that I am using as requested by @m3n7alsnak3